# Android RatingBar can't set rating

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, ratingbar

I'm trying to implement a RatingBar in my Android app but I'm running into some issues when trying to set the rating. My bar is always displayed as having the maximum available rating. Below are my files:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ratingBarStyling" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">25dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">27dip</item>
</style>
```

(same for v21)

**star_rating_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_empty" />
<item android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_empty" />
<item android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

**star_rating_bar_full_empty**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty" />

</selector>
```

**star_rating_bar_full_filled**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />

</selector>
```

And finally the implementation of the RatingBar on the Fragment layout:

```
<RatingBar
        style="@style/ratingBarStyling"
        android:id="@+id/venue_card_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="2.0"/>
```

Now for some reason I can see the filled star icons but non of the empty ones. I have also tried setting it programmatically but the results were the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I'm always getting: [stars.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viTpd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made small mistake/typo
You will have to use android:id instead of providing a new id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_rating_bar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```